# expected 8 or 0 byte long (4)

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am new to cassandra.I am using latest version of cassandra.I am getting the exception "expected 8 or 0 byte long (4)" when inserting the data in the newly added table.I am using CassandracsharpDriver in .net. My code and Query is

Code Block :

```
Query : string query =
   "INSERT INTO test_table(Id,Name,Date,CreatedOn) values (?,?,?,?)";

BatchStatement("_test", query, 394741470, "test", "2019-05-06");

public void BatchStatement(string keySpace, string query,params object[] parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            BatchStatement objBatchStatement = new BatchStatement();
            PreparedStatement statement = PrepareQueryStatement(keySpace, query);
            objBatchStatement.Add(statement.Bind(parameter));
            var session = cluster.Connect(keySpace);
            //objBatchStatement.ConsistencyLevel
            // Execute the batch
            // RowSet row = session.Execute(query);
            RowSet row = session.Execute(objBatchStatement);

        }            
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excpetion occured during batch operation method Name BatchStatement error : " + ex.ToString());
        }

    }

//session.Execute(objBatchStatement); code is throwing excpetion expected 8 or 0 byte long (4)
```

Thanks

Comment: With simple query it is working but not working with Batchstatement. I have to insert multiple record in the cassandra.

Comment: If the `CreatedOn` has a default value, it should be skipped in the query. `"INSERT INTO test_table(Id,Name,Date) values (?,?,?)";`

Answer (score 3):

Guess: This is a classic case of Value type inference.
You are using the query:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(Id,Name,Date,CreatedOn) values (?,?,?,?)";

BatchStatement("_test", query, 394741470, "test", "2019-05-06");
```

Here, 394741470 is an int in C#. So the driver serializes it as a CQL int (4 bytes), but the server expects a CQL bigint (8 bytes). The fix is to specify the correct type:

You can try the following:

```
BatchStatement("_test", query, 394741470L, "test", "2019-05-06");
```

OR it may be issue with date. Your date is string. Try using DateTime.

```
BatchStatement("_test", query, 394741470L, "test", Convert.ToDateTime("2019-05-06"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check data type of Cassandra table and use corresponding datatype of java and use it in java code when declaring variable to pass value of column .

Example : In Cassandra bigint then define long in java instead int.

check this [type mapping between Cassandra vs Java](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping)